# Trying docker in docker getting TCP connection refused error

Tags: tcp, docker

I am  trying to run docker in docker and getting **TCP 127.0.0.1:5000: connection refused**. Can someone explain why this happened and how I can fix it.

Here is what I have tired:

```
docker run -it --privileged --name docker-server-test -d docker:1.7-dind

docker run --rm --link docker-server:docker docker:1.7 pull my-server:5000/qe/busybox
Unable to find image 'docker:1.7' locally
Trying to pull repository docker.io/library/docker ... 1.7: Pulling from library/docker
f4fddc471ec2: Already exists 
da0daae25b21: Already exists 
413668359dd0: Already exists 
ab205815427f: Already exists 
e8ace195c6b6: Already exists 
2129588b76a3: Already exists 
63f71ebd654b: Already exists 
f3231b3888dd: Already exists 
d449c5a1e017: Already exists 

library/docker:1.7: The image you are pulling has been verified. 
Important: image verification is a tech preview feature and should not be relied on to provide security.
Digest: sha256:c3666cc6458e02d780492c75acf1b0bf3424c8dd6882361438a9b93b46c2aa55
Status: Downloaded newer image for docker.io/docker:1.7

Pulling repository my-server:5000/qe/busybox
Get http://localhost:5000/v1/repositories/qe/busybox/tags: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:5000: connection refused
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to pull an image from a registry running on your local machine -- in this case when you specify `localhost` as the place to pull the image from, it's trying to pull from `localhost` relative to the Docker daemon container (which isn't where your registry is listening).  You probably want to instead pull from `host-ip:5000/qe/busybox` (likely something like `192.168.0.x:5000/qe/busybox`).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion here is what I get now host-ip:5000/qe/busybox
Using default tag: latest
Error response from daemon: unable to ping registry endpoint https://host-ip:5000/v0/
v2 ping attempt failed with error: Get https://host-ip:5000/v2/: tls: oversized record received with length 20527
 v1 ping attempt failed with error: Get https://host-ip:5000/v1/_ping: tls: oversized record received with length 20527

Comment: Is your registry configured with TLS certificates?

Answer (score 0):

Did you have env variable set? Based on your OS, set following Docker env variables if not already set:

1. DOCKER_HOST
2. **DOCKER_CERT_PATH**
3. **DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY**

You can get these details from your docker client

```
docker-machine env default
```